# UIApplicationDelegate calls on Mac Catalyst

Tags: mac-catalyst

I'm converting an iOS to macOS using Catalyst.   I'm finding that some of the UIApplicationDelegate functions are not getting called on Mac.

application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is called
applicationDidEnterBackground(*) is called when the app is quit

However, nothing is called when the app is hidden or when it is put into the background.  I really need to execute some code when those events happen.  Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: I found this article confirming that the background and foreground methods aren't called: https://appventure.me/guides/catalyst/how/app_lifecycle.html. I would also like to find an alternative.

Comment: I think we should report this as a bug (or feature request) with Apple.  I have made a few changes so it is not critical that I get these notifications, but it would be nice.

Comment: If you close the macOS Catalyst app using the red close button on the top left of the window, the UIApplication lifecycle is invoked. If you press Stop on Xcode, it will not trigger the UIApplication lifecycle, but will terminate the app anyway.